# How to send message to not subscribed user in Viber

Tags: viber, viber-api

Is this possible to send message via Viber Api to not subscribed user by means of Viber Bot. I can't find any info on that in docs: https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#send-message. But i constantly receive message from companies i've never subscribed to, so it seems feasible

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Viber Business Messages](https://www.forbusiness.viber.com/en/messaging-solutions/) instead. Because Viber Bot API is for another purpose.

For that, you need to use one of [Viber Messaging Partners](https://www.forbusiness.viber.com/en/messaging-partners/) and use their API (not Viber) to send messages. Then you'll be able to send promotional and transactional messages to your auditory.